# How to increase the printing quality when using abs (slicer config)?

Tags: abs, slicing

I have checked several different sites giving different configurations for the slicer. Let's say that the average extruder temperature is 230°C. I know that the complexity of the object matters a lot for the printing quality. What I am concerning is the deposition rate (mm/min), and, the infill type (e.g. honeycomb, rectangular). Which impact the inner infill has in the printing quality? Due to time reasons maximal allowed infill is 50%.

I have a Geetech Prusa REpRap I3.

Thanks for you help guys!!

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help you out...

Iam using a Ultimaker 2+, **only** with ABS filament, and the software Cura. Cura is a good software but you cannot edit every option like in other slicers, Iam just using the default ABS profile.

Most of the times Iam printing in 0.2mm quality, speed varies, smaller objects get printed slower. My max speed when printing is 40mm/s.

The Buildplate heats up to 90°, I tend to increase the heat to 98° - 100°.
The more I increase that the lesser warping I will get. But Iam using bluetape also, so warping is no big issue anyway.
The noozle should be heated to 260°, thats the cura default.

On very small or thin parts I activate the fan immediatly, on big parts Iam not using the fan. I also print the small parts really slow.

I had no problems regarding the outer-walls and the infill (no cave building or stuff like that), but this is maybe dependent on the outer-wall-thickness. I mostly use a wall-thickness of over 1mm. Iam always using rectangular pattern, and mostly an infill under 30%.

I get good quality prints, and nearly no warping because of the bluetape.

Otherwise I didnt change any options in Cura, the flow rate is default.

---

Sorry for the late edit, here are my default cura settings:
[image: Basic Settings]
[image: Advanced Settings]

Comment: Hello @ LWS-Mo. Interesting, so your speed configuration is dynamic. It is a bit abstract for me to imagine your deposition rate just with what you wrote. I will take a look at the Cura software and I will select the parameters that you have said. I did not try to make the nozzle temperature so high (I need to check if it is possible for my printer to achieve such high temperatures). I agree with you, for most of the applications 30% infill or less is enough. Does you it have problems with detachment of the abs from the heating bed?

Comment: I will also check Cura again to post more of my settings. I had problems with the detachment of the object on the start, but than I discovered bluetape. Since using this all prints stick really good to the bed. I have to remove the prints from the still hot buildplate, otherwise its really hard to get the object of the plate. So it really sticks.